# How to save String value and print it on another page using Google Chrome storage API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-api, google-chrome-devtools

I am looking to take user input in and then saving that user input using the google chrome storage api but I cannot find any useful reasources on this topic.

I have 2 elements that I would wish to save permanently using JS:

```
 var title = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('title').value);
var url = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('url').value);
```

I want to create an 2 arrays, one that holds the title values and one that holds the url values, then I want to print those values out on another page.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you looking to save the values locally on the browser? If so, you're probably looking for localstorage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage

Answer (score 0):

You can use chrome.storage.local object to accomplish that.

**If you need to store data in the chrome storage use the following sentence:**

```
chrome.storage.local.set({'titles': [title]});
chrome.storage.local.set({'urls': [url]});
```

**Now, if you want to retrieve the current data in the chrome storage use the following:**

```
let newTile = "new title";
chrome.storage.local.get('titles', function(titles){
    titles.push(newTile);
    chrome.storage.local.set({'titles': titles});
});

let newUrl = "http://.....";
chrome.storage.local.get('urls', function(urls){
    urls.push(newUrl);
    chrome.storage.local.set({'urls': urls});
});
```

**Important:**  What is missing here, are the conditions to check current data in the local storage.

**Hope this helps!**